# Expandablelistview custom groupview to high

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have Expandablelistview with custom UI. I defined adapter extended from BaseExpandableListAdapter. I want my groupviews to be exactly 25dp height, but they are higher

my xml is `

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="@string/products"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/weight_g"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/measure"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

`

and my code

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition,
            final boolean isExpanded, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context,
                R.layout.header_measurements, null);

        final TextView title = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        title.setText(data.get(groupPosition).categoryName);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you left out the most important part. what does the container (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, etc) of your textviews in the xml say? the layout height should either say `android:layout_height="25dp"` or  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`